# create profile in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a profile called STUDENT, but I have no idea how to setup resources and password parameters, below are my exact code. Can you leave me some examples?

`CREATE PROFILE STUDENT LIMIT { resource_parameters | password_parameters };`

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-02376: invalid or redundant resource

You can give examples with any limit. I just need to see which part is a temple while which part is the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As you requested: example of setting up `RESOURCE` and `PASSWORD` parameters, taken straight from the documentation.

```
SQL> create profile test_profile limit
  2    -- this is one of the RESOURCE parameters
  3    sessions_per_user 1
  4    -- this is one of the PASSWORD parameters
  5    failed_login_attempts  default
  6  /

Profile created.

SQL>
```